# Painting Grahpics2D Object on Frame with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, graphics2d, gridbaglayout

I am trying to draw a coloured bar, which gets bigger as time goes on. It works when I use the default layoutmanager, but when im trying to implement this with GridBagLayout it wont. I wrote a test project just for testing purposes to investigate what the problem is. I added a few buttons just to have something else apart from the graphics2D object, so it kinda looks like my actual project im working on. But after a couple of days, i have to admit that i dont have a clue, what is going wrong. I hope someone can help me!

Just in advance, dont get confused by some words i used in the code. my mother tongue isn't english.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Timer;


public class FarbBalkenTest extends JPanel {

static Timer timer = new Timer ();
static TimerTask task ;
static int time;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FarbBalkenTest fbt = new FarbBalkenTest();
    fbt.init();


}

public static void addComponent(Container cont, GridBagLayout gbl, Component c, int x, int y, int width, int height, double weightx, double weighty ){

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.gridx=x;
    gbc.gridy=y;
    gbc.gridwidth=width;gbc.gridheight=height;
    gbc.weightx=weightx;gbc.weighty=weighty;
    gbl.setConstraints(c,gbc);
    cont.add(c);

}


public void init (){

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
    Container c = frame.getContentPane();
    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
    c.setLayout(gbl);
    ZeichenTest z_test = new ZeichenTest();

    addComponent(c,gbl, new Button("top left"), 0,0,1,1,1.0,1.0);
    addComponent(c,gbl, new Button("top right"), 2,0, 1,1,1.0,1.0);
    addComponent(c, gbl,z_test, 1,1,1,1,1.0,1.0);
    addComponent(c,gbl, new Button("down left"),0,2,1,1,1.0,1.0);
    addComponent(c,gbl, new Button("down right"),2,2,1,1,1.0,1.0);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    task = new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            frame.repaint();
            time+= 20;
            System.out.println(time);
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);



}
public class ZeichenTest extends JComponent  {

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            Color startgreen = new Color(50,205,50);

            Color endred = new Color (255, 97, 3);

            GradientPaint startend = new GradientPaint(0,25 , startgreen, 400, 25 , endred );

            g2d.setPaint (startend);

            g2d.fillRect(50, 200 , time, 50);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: the problem was that I couldnt see the bar, which I wanted to draw, only the buttons. But the problem is solved, I just had to change the position of my rectangle to (0,0) so the buttons wouldnt overlay the bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "It works when I use the default layoutmanager, but when im trying to implement this with GridBagLayout it wont."

GBL respects preferred sizes. Your `ZeichenTest` has none. You need to explicitly set it by overriding `getPreferredSize()`. (The default layout of JFrame which is BorderLayout doesn't respect preferred sizes, and will stretch you panel to fit)

```
public class ZeichenTest extends JComponent {
    ...
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension( ... , ... );
    }
}
```

Also note, after setting the preferred size of the component, just call `pack()` on the frame, instead of `setSize()`. The `pack()` will "fit" everything according to the preferred sizes. You can actually test that your component currently has no preferred size by calling `pack()` instead of `setSize()` and you will see the frame shrink on launching. But if you override the `getPreferredSize()` of the component and call pack, the frame will be size according the new preferred size.

---

Other Important notes:

- Use `java.swing.Timer` instead of `TimerTask`. repaints should be done on the EDT and Swing Timer handles this for you. See more at [How to Use Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- I think you mean to `repaint()` the instance of `ZeichenTest` and *not* the frame. It makes a difference.
- Always call `super.paintComponent` in your `paintComponent` method, as to not leave nasty paint atrifacts

  ```
  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
  }
  ```
- Swing apps should always be run on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). Basically, in this case, just wrap the `main` code in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
          public void run() {
              FarbBalkenTest fbt = new FarbBalkenTest();
              fbt.init();
          }
      });
  }
  ```

Comment: Thx a lot, mate!
Though I did use setPreferredSize in the constructor in my real project for the bar. I wrote this in a hurry, so i forgot a few things.
But thanks for the additional advices. I will look them through when i get home today. I was able to find the solution for my problem, and it was quite simple. I had to paint the rectangle at (0,0), otherwise the buttons would overlay the bar i want to draw. I felt a bit stupid, cause the solution was so obvious. But anyway, thanks again!